# how check values in data series?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following series

I want to check user input num(Mobile num) is in one of that series.

```
public class MobilePhoneSeries
{
    public long SeriesStart { get; set; }
    public long SeriesEnd { get; set; }

    private IEnumerable<MobilePhoneSeries> DummyGetMobilePhoneSeries()
    {
        IList<MobilePhoneSeries> dummDtos = new List<MobilePhoneSeries>()
        {
            new MobilePhoneSeries(){SeriesStart = 40000000, SeriesEnd =49999999 },
            new MobilePhoneSeries(){SeriesStart = 46700000000, SeriesEnd = 46799999999 },
            new MobilePhoneSeries(){SeriesStart = 90000000, SeriesEnd = 99999999 }
        };
        return dummDtos;
    }
    private bool MobilePhoneSeriesValidation(string num)
    {
        var res = DummyGetMobilePhoneSeries();
        //??????????????????
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `num` format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you better pass long to the method `MobilePhoneSeriesValidation` instead of passing `string`. As you have to compare it with `long`.

```
private bool MobilePhoneSeriesValidation(string num)
{
     long numLong = long.Parse(num);
     var res = DummyGetMobilePhoneSeries();
     return res.Any(c=> c.SeriesStart <=numLong &&  c.SeriesEnd  >= numLong );
}
```

If you pass the `long` to `MobilePhoneSeriesValidation` instead of string.

```
private bool MobilePhoneSeriesValidation(long num)
{
    var res = DummyGetMobilePhoneSeries();
    return res.Any(c=> c.SeriesStart <=numLong &&  c.SeriesEnd  >= numLong );    
}
```

Comment: I missed that statement you have, check my answer now.